# How to rename All files SRC Attribute value to lowercase?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rename

I have multiple HTML code files that contain `SRC` attribute values like this:

Value 1

`<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/102.gif" WIDTH="309" HEIGHT="106">`

Value 2

`<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/arc3.gif" ALT="Radian measure" WIDTH="365" HEIGHT="101">`

Value 3

`<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/trigA.gif" WIDTH="590" HEIGHT="151" alt="Trigonometry">`

Value 4

`<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/30-60aa.gif" WIDTH="95" HEIGHT="115" alt="30-60-90 triangle">`

But I have so many files that contains this type of SRC Attribute value.

but I have to rename all files **SRC Attribute** values to lowercase. like this

Output 1

`<IMG SRC="trig_img/102.gif" WIDTH="309" HEIGHT="106">`

Output 2

`<IMG SRC="trig_img/arc3.gif" ALT="Radian measure" WIDTH="365" HEIGHT="101">`

Output 3

`<IMG SRC="trig_img/triga.gif" WIDTH="590" HEIGHT="151" alt="Trigonometry"`

Output 4

`<IMG SRC="trig_img/30-60aa.gif" WIDTH="95" HEIGHT="115" alt="30-60-90 triangle">`

Is there any possible way  to rename the `SRC` attribute values to lowercase?

Comment: In your code editor use the find and replace function. On windows it's `CTRL+H`. You can also do it programmatically but that depends on language you want to use.

Comment: @AbuNooh thank you for your answer. I knew I can achieve with find and replace function but SRC Attribute Values are different in all files I want to rename all at once because if I go with find and replace for each line it will take maybe a month or more than a month time to rename all SRC Attribute value to lowercase values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript to fix the attributes after you have loaded the HTML; use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find all the images, and then [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to change the values:

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');

imgs.forEach(i => i.setAttribute('src', i.getAttribute('src').toLowerCase()));
```

```html
<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/102.gif" WIDTH="309" HEIGHT="106">
<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/arc3.gif" ALT="Radian measure" WIDTH="365" HEIGHT="101">
<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/trigA.gif" WIDTH="590" HEIGHT="151" alt="Trigonometry">
<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/30-60aa.gif" WIDTH="95" HEIGHT="115" alt="30-60-90 triangle">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get elements by tag name and change the src:

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) { 
  images[i].src = images[i].src.toLowerCase()
}
```

```html
<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/102.gif" WIDTH="309" HEIGHT="106" />
<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/arc3.gif" ALT="Radian measure" WIDTH="365" HEIGHT="101" />
<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/trigA.gif" WIDTH="590" HEIGHT="151" alt="Trigonometry" />
<IMG SRC="Trig_IMG/30-60aa.gif" WIDTH="95" HEIGHT="115" alt="30-60-90 triangle" />
```

Comment: your answer was correct also but it will get whole FULL SRC path instead of I wanted 'Trig_IMG/102.gif'. by the way thank you for your answer.